# what is the lifecyle of javascript code bound to a script tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I am relatively new to web apps and currently working my way through some of the beautiful new technologies and frameworks while working on a webapp.

I have recently been moving towards a one page app by using jquery.load() to reload parts of my page at runtime.

So far I had scripts embedded in my partial webpages and used a custom event to initialize them instead of using $('document').ready() which does no get fired when using load.

Now I am wondering what actually happens to my javascript code when the part of the page their script tag resides in is replaced by another page fragment.

Obviously the script tags DOM element is discarded but what happens to the functions, variables, handlers and so on ? Are they still available or are the handlers that I registered now undefined and throw exceptions when they are triggered ?

Currently I am looking at require.js and I wonder if that will (depending on the answers to the above questions) change the lifecycle of my scripts because being loaded by require.js they are not bound to a DOM element that is likely to be discarded ?

Cheers Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a browser parses a `<script>` tag, everything stops, and the code is evaluated. As soon as the execution starts, the `<script>` tag is irrelevant - it can even be removed by the very code it contains. If the script created any global variables, they persist in the global variable space; if it defined functions, ditto; if it bound some listeners, they will continue listening. Removing the script will not affect the global space (and in particular, it will not rewind time and erase any changes the script execution produced).

Dynamic JS loaders like Require.js do this: fetch code text by AJAX, create a script element, then insert it into the document, which makes the browser do the above. The only difference is when this happens: a `<script>` tag pauses everything until the code is executed (unless it was marked by `defer`), while Require.js handles the timing of each script's execution (and giving you dependency resolution to control that timing).

Most applications would be better off not loading JS in AJAX pages, simply because - as you find - AJAX-loaded JS doesn't clean up after itself automatically, instead applying functions from JS you loaded in the main page. It is not an unbreakable law, though.